# OpenSSL AES encryption error

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm currently trying to encrypt a binary file with OpenSSL (it's part of a project and OpenSSL has to be used).I managed to install OpenSSL and link it with Visual Studio 2010.

Upon finishing my program I did not get any underlined errors but on compileing i get the following

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AES_ctr128_encrypt referenced in function "void __cdecl encrypt(void)"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is from linker. Probably, you didn't enable some ifdefs, or didn't set some compiler options.
To troubleshoot this error, 
- check where AES_ctr128_encrypt is defined and check if you are compiling corresponding file 
- check if this file is linked together in project 
- check compiled object file if it exports this function with the name _AES_ctr128_encrypt

Comment: you were absolutely right.I had to add Additional Dependencies to the Linked, and then it worked perfectly.Thank you!